# Default language not working with email confirmation message

Tags: email, language, activation

Even if the default language is set in portuguese in the Control Panel, when a member receives an account activation email and click on it, the success message appears in english.

The member receives in his email box the activation link:

```
https://www.mysite.com/?ACT=190&id=SZMyPGQEmG
```

**Once clicked an english message appears (normally should be in portuguese, because all the text are translated in this language):**

[image]

For this kind of email box the activation link, **the default language setting (portuguese) is not applied**. To be in portuguese i have to translate this file:

```
system\ee\legacy\language\english\member_lang.php
```

Is there a configuration in the Control Panel, or a System Configuration Overrides to insert inside config.php file, to activate the language setting about activation messages?

Comment: Same problem here. Also not working with json errors with Channel Form Tag

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying the language pack installed isn't loading that lang file and is instead defaulting to English? I think this is the file and pack you need:

https://github.com/EllisLab/EE-Language-Brazilian-Portuguese/blob/master/system/user/language/pt-br/member_lang.php

Make sure to set the installed pack as the default language:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/languages.html#installing-a-language-pack

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/languages.html#setting-the-default-language

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. The pt-br language pack is installed and set as default language. Works very well in the control panel, error messages, except for email confirmation message. Even if the language pt-br is set as default language, the email confirmation message use the english one.